# How to detect lines using HoughLines in OpenCV (Java)?

Tags: java, opencv

I'm currently trying to detect whether a level crossing barrier has been deployed on an image using `HoughLines` in `OpenCV`. I thought my code would draw a line on my image, so long as the barrier appears in it - but instead I get an error message saying "Mat data type is not compatible". Can show me how to detect lines in Java with OpenCV?

```
public class DetectLines {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

    Mat eventless = Highgui.imread("files/eventless.png");
    Mat barrier = Highgui.imread("files/barrier/lc-00201.png");
    Mat difference = new Mat();
    Mat lines = new Mat();

    Core.absdiff(eventless, barrier, difference);

    Mat grey = new Mat();
    Imgproc.cvtColor(difference, grey, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    Imgproc.HoughLines(grey, lines, 5.0, 4.0, 7);

    Imshow ims1 = new Imshow("Lines");
    ims1.showImage(lines);

}

}
```

Answer (score 9):

The lines are returned in the lines matrix, which has two columns in which each line returns the rho and theta parameters of the polar coordinates. These coordinates refer to the distance between the top-left corner of the image and the line rotation in radians, respectively. So, in order to use the show method you must create a Mat that will represent the lines using the line coordinates.

```
  public Mat getHoughTransform(Mat image, double rho, double theta, int threshold) {
    Mat result = Image.getInstance().getImage().clone();
    Mat lines = new Mat();
    Imgproc.HoughLines(image, lines, rho, theta, threshold);

    for (int i = 0; i < lines.cols(); i++) {
        double data[] = lines.get(0, i);
        double rho1 = data[0];
        double theta1 = data[1];
        double cosTheta = Math.cos(theta1);
        double sinTheta = Math.sin(theta1);
        double x0 = cosTheta * rho1;
        double y0 = sinTheta * rho1;
        Point pt1 = new Point(x0 + 10000 * (-sinTheta), y0 + 10000 * cosTheta);
        Point pt2 = new Point(x0 - 10000 * (-sinTheta), y0 - 10000 * cosTheta);
        Imgproc.line(result, pt1, pt2, new Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2);
    }
    return result;
}
```

And this is a easier way to do it. It involve the Imgproc.HoughLinesP method.

```
public Mat getHoughPTransform(Mat image, double rho, double theta, int threshold) {
    Mat result = Image.getInstance().getImage().clone();
    Mat lines = new Mat();
    Imgproc.HoughLinesP(image, lines, rho, theta, threshold);

    for (int i = 0; i < lines.cols(); i++) {
        double[] val = lines.get(0, i);
        Imgproc.line(result, new Point(val[0], val[1]), new Point(val[2], val[3]), new Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: lines are returned in rows not columns - therefore use `lines.cols()` in loop and `lines.get(i, 0)`

Answer (score 1):

in Android or Java its the same idia.you must to do it in for ();
to get the theta and row 
after you get start point and the end point ,you can core the line.(core.line)
but dont forget to transfer the mat that you get the values from her to other.
after this>>release the mat.
hope thats its help u.
r.i
enjoy

Answer (score -1):

Edit: See [lordache's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/42598538/revisions) which is Java specific.

Useful reading: [How are two-element vector represented in a OpenCV Mat in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29517069/how-are-two-element-vector-represented-in-a-opencv-mat-in-java)

---

Check [this tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html#standard-and-probabilistic-hough-line-transform) and look for the section "Standard Hough Line Transform".

`lines` should not be a `cv::Mat`, but a `std::vector<cv::Vec2f> lines;` that later on you can visualize with a code like the one showed in the link:

```
for( size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++ )
{
  float rho = lines[i][0], theta = lines[i][1];
  Point pt1, pt2;
  double a = cos(theta), b = sin(theta);
  double x0 = a*rho, y0 = b*rho;
  pt1.x = cvRound(x0 + 1000*(-b));
  pt1.y = cvRound(y0 + 1000*(a));
  pt2.x = cvRound(x0 - 1000*(-b));
  pt2.y = cvRound(y0 - 1000*(a));
  line( cdst, pt1, pt2, Scalar(0,0,255), 3, CV_AA);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Is there any chance you could write it in Java though? That's the trouble I'm having - almost all the tutorials are for C++ or Python...

Comment: @Zetland Interesting. Where's the Java interface defined? In fact it's not documented at all on OpenCV guide. Besides, I haven't written in Java for ages, I won't be able to support you in the translation.

Comment: I don't know if it's defined anywhere. It's very annoying. I'm having to use it for my course...

Comment: @Zetland You have something here: http://docs.opencv.org/java/. You can search it in google by using `<search terms> site:http://docs.opencv.org/java/`. For example I can get to [this function description](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.2/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html#HoughLines%28org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat,%20double,%20double,%20int%29). You are right, `lines` are returned as a `Mat` (not something you can draw though), but the documentation on the parameter is stubbornly the same of the C++ interface. You should inform your teacher about how poor is the documentation.

Comment: @Zetland I have posted [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29517069/how-are-two-element-vector-represented-in-a-mat-in-java)

Comment: @Zetland I got an answer to [the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29517069/how-are-two-element-vector-represented-in-a-mat-in-java), can you let me/him know if it works?

Comment: @Octopus Sure, at the time there was nobody able to support OP in Java, then (years after) lordache's answer came.