# How are two-element vector represented in a OpenCV Mat in Java?

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing

I was looking at [Opencv Java documentation of Hough Transform](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.2/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html#HoughLines%28org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat,%20double,%20double,%20int%29).

The return value `lines` is in a `Mat` data type described as:

> Output vector of lines. Each line is represented by a two-element
>   vector (rho, theta). rho is the distance from the coordinate origin
>   (0,0) (top-left corner of the image). theta is the line rotation angle
>   in radians (0 ~ vertical line, pi/2 ~ horizontal line).

Curiously, this description matches [the C++ interface's description](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=houghlines#houghlines), **but** the data type not: in C++ you can use a `std::vector<cv::Vec2f> lines` as described in [this tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html#standard-and-probabilistic-hough-line-transform). In C++ the returned data representation, given the description, is straightforward, but in Java not.

So, in Java, how are the two-element vector represented/stored in the returned Mat?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's some code I used a while ago, in version 2.4.8 I think. `matLines` came from this:

```
Imgproc.HoughLinesP(matOutline, matLines, 1, Math.PI / 180, houghThreshCurrent, houghMinLength, houghMaxGap);
```

...

```
Point[] points = new Point[]{ new Point(), new Point() };
for (int x = 0; x < matLines.cols(); x++) {
   double[] vec = matLines.get(0, x);
   points[0].x = vec[0];
   points[0].y = vec[1];
   points[1].x = vec[2];
   points[1].y = vec[3];
   //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I am actually not the one in need, let's see what the author of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29493267/how-to-detect-lines-using-houghlines-in-opencv-java) says...

Comment: I've taken the liberty to rewrite the loop to avoid unnecessary memory allocation in the loop; for big pictures, this can be a real resource hog.