# Sort bounding boxes with Tl() : Opencv Android

Tags: java, android, opencv, contour, bounding-box

I am trying to sort the bounding boxes with y axis and then x axis but the results I find from tl().x and tl().y are bit confusing and after lot of work I couldn't find anything in documentation. Here are some results please take a look. I want them to be in order from 1 to 30

CODE:

```
m = Utils.loadResource(MainActivity.this, R.drawable.sheet1, Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
//Mat original = Utils.loadResource(MainActivity.this, R.drawable.sheet1, Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(m.cols(), m.rows(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

Imgproc.cvtColor(m, m, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
Imgproc.medianBlur(m, m,3); 
Imgproc.threshold(m, m, 0, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU);
Core.bitwise_not(m, m);
Imgproc.dilate(m, m, Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new Size(1,118)));

java.util.List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();                  
Imgproc.findContours(m.clone(), contours, new Mat() ,Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL , Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
Rect rect = Imgproc.boundingRect(contours.get(35));                         
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "TL:"+rect.tl()+"BR:"+rect.br(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

[image]

EDIT:

This is cropped region and the coordinates showing above are of these boxes.
[image]

Original Image:

[image]

Comment: Please offer some more background on the scenario and narrow the scope of your question - what, specifically, are you confused about/do you need help doing?

Comment: If you can also list which areas of the documentation you looked to for help on your problem it can help us to get you an answer more quickly.

Comment: @snickers10m I tried to look for bounding boxes

Comment: Alright, please add any new information to your post with the "edit" button (beneath the tags you listed) that's the best place to put it. Then, continue with the other issues I pointed out with your question.

Comment: @snickers10m MCQ 16 to onwards are on the right side of the image but why their y component is less ?

Comment: @Antonio I have added the code above

Comment: @Antonio Contours are correct from bounding boxes I have cropped the region and showed them in ImageView which gives the correct boxes but fro your satisfaction I have added the code above.

Comment: @Antonio Cropped egios is added

Comment: @Antonio tl().x and tl().y gives the same results and I have uploaded the image like its shown above but when it gives the resultant image it is rotated

Comment: @HelpingDesk Ok, so the results you have are perfectly reasonable (your input image is rotated, so x and y are swapped). I struggle to understand what's your problem.

Comment: @Antonio and how does it happen? and how to solve it?

Comment: @HelpingDesk Well, isn't your input image simply rotated? If you need to rotate it after loading in opencv, you can check how this is done in C++: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23990392/2436175

Comment: @Antonio Ok If input image is rotated I have applied dialation horizontally how does it combined the circles?

Comment: @Antonio I have added the code please check

Comment: @HelpingDesk Please ask a clear question, I still do not understand what is your problem.

Comment: @Antonio I just want at contour(0) it should be MCQ number 1 and at contour(1) MCQ number 2 and so on

Comment: @HelpingDesk What's MCQ number?

Comment: @Antonio If you look at the image above it has an index before circles in each row

Answer (score 1):

So you want to sort with priority first left to right and then top to bottom. x coordinate is more important, however for *similar* x what counts is the y. Write a sorting function, in which you have a relationship which in pseudocode looks like this:

```
boolean isLessThan(bboxA,bboxB,unsigned int tolerance = 100) {

    if (bboxA.tl().x + tolerance < bboxB.tl().x);
         return true;
    if (bboxB.tl().x + tolerance < bboxA.tl().x);
         return false;
    return (bboxA.tl().y < bboxB.tl().y);

    }
```

(Or hardcode `tolerance`)

Comment: what is tolerance here?

Comment: @HelpingDesk For similar x (displacement from the left side), what counts is the y coordinate. To define "similar" you use a threshold: if their difference of their x coordinates is within this threshold, than you have to check the y coordinate. I call this threshold "tolerance".